# Background images in css are not getting cached

Tags: css, reactjs, caching

I have some react code that is rendering content dynamically via `React.createElement`. As such, css is applied via an object. Elements in that dynamic generation can have background image, pointing to a public aws S3 bucket.

It seems that every time my components re-render, the background images are being fetched again from S3. This is delaying the page render. I have S3 meta-data for Cache-Control set on all the objects . Here are request and response headers for background image load -

Response header -

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800
Content-Length: 52532
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Sun, 06 Feb 2022 05:57:32 GMT
ETag: "f29655808a5f80627d9ea7f44058a5e3"
Last-Modified: Sun, 06 Feb 2022 05:55:10 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
x-amz-meta-filetype: IMAGE
```

Request Header -

```
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host:  <bucket-name>s3.amazonaws.com
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://<my-domain>.com/
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36
```

I can see in Network tab that images are being loaded multiple times and it also shows data transfers being done everytime. What am I doing wrong here? Can someone please help finding the root cause. Thanks.

Comment: Before someone says it, I know the size of background image is too large, but since it is user defined, user is allowed to upload images upto certain sizes. This request/response for a test data. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Hi @zookastos can you confirm me that the `ETag` header does not change between the different calls? Also does your url changes in some way from a call to another? Could you consider a preload phase with an image element?

Comment: Please give me some time to get back to you with this info. Meanwhile, can you please let me know what is meant by "preload phase". Any link to doc would be nice. Thanks

Comment: Take your time and also have a look to this good article, it could help to understant the "preload phase": [Better Image Caching with CSS](https://perishablepress.com/css-image-caching/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, for this documentation

Comment: @DDomen can you please post this as an answer? "preload phase" seemed to work for me with as little code as possible. Thanks

Comment: have you checked the [btargac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71251973/13332423)? If yes, did you added the image source as an element and then created the dynamic element?

Comment: I tried created elements dynamically and it seemed to work partially. But @btargac's answer was spot it. No need to actually dynamically create elements after unchecking that checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could it be a forgotten "disable cache" option selected in the network tab in the dev tools ? Because it seems the server responds with the correct type of cache headers.

Comment: Holy hell, this was it. So many hours and 50 reputation spent to find this small checkbox :) Thank you, and sorry for wasting everyone's time. Hope it helps others in future.

Answer (score 1):

If images are optimized and not huge, using base64 data url is a good solution.

```
const getBase64FromUrl = async (url) => {
  const data = await fetch(url);
  const blob = await data.blob();
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const base64data = reader.result;   
      resolve(base64data);
    }
  });
}

const image = getBase64FromUrl('the image url')
```

While creating the element you can use

```
background-image: `url(${image})`;
```

In addition, rarely do we serve from S3 directly, you should probably use cloudfront as a proxy to

- reduce get request
- reduce bandwidth charges
- cache at cdn
- better control of cache headers
- hide your s3 real url

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing a network request is probably because you're using the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header in your request.

As seen here:

> The no-cache response directive indicates that the response can be
> stored in caches, but the response must be validated with the origin
> server before each reuse, even when the cache is disconnected from the
> origin server.
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> If you want caches to always check for content
> updates while reusing stored content, no-cache is the directive to
> use. It does this by requiring caches to revalidate each request with
> the origin server.
>
> Note that no-cache does not mean "don't cache". no-cache allows caches
> to store a response but requires them to revalidate it before reuse.
> If the sense of "don't cache" that you want is actually "don't store",
> then no-store is the directive to use.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#response_directives

Here is what a full request for a cached asset looks like on my network tab, when the asset returns 304 Not Modified from the validation request. (from S3) This is in a `background: url` context.

[image]

Comment: I am not passing any cache-control header in my request via fetch. This is background-image url set by css - background: url('<url-here'); https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url()

Comment: That's the request header... Does not mean nothing for server-side

Comment: If I load a cached image via `background: url`, I see a network request every time, which returns 304 Not Modified. For example, with a 1mb image, there is 390 bytes transferred over network to check the status. The validation request takes 155ms. If the endpoint doesn't return Not Modified, then the whole image is requested.

Comment: Also, it's possible to invalidate an asset cache if you add url params like ?2412314, so maybe check for that as well.

Comment: Okay, can you please show your request, response headers. Thanks for inputs on this.

Comment: How do I control the Cache-Control header in request, in context of background-url?

Comment: You can't control requests from css unless you change the underlying browser settings. It also looks like the `Last-Modified` date returned in the response was very close to when you made the request, so that would invalidate the cache if you modified the asset. The header returned by S3 looks correct, `max-age=604800`. Another thing to keep in mind is browsers have a total max storage, so you might want to try clearing your browser cache if all else fails.

Comment: The date is closer because I was experimenting with various values in S3 Cache-Control meta data, and a file was recently uploaded there

Answer (score 0):

While I also had the "Disable cache" option checked in my dev tools, I had to send `{ cache: 'force-cache' }` as the init argument. Without it the response items still were not being cached.

E.g.:

```
fetch(someUrl, { cache: 'force-cache' })
```